# GroupByKey node from BigQueryIO.writeTableRows() does not emit elements

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

My streaming dataflow pipeline, which pulls data from PubSub, doesn't write away to BigQuery and logs no errors. The elements go into the node "Write to BigQuery/StreamingInserts/StreamingWriteTables/Reshuffle/GroupByKey":

[image]

which is created implicitly like this:

```
PCollection<TableRow> rows = ...;
rows.apply("Write to BigQuery",
    BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().to(poptions.getOutputTableName())
        .withSchema(...)
        .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
        .withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STREAMING_INSERTS)
        .withFailedInsertRetryPolicy(InsertRetryPolicy.alwaysRetry())
        .withExtendedErrorInfo());
```

But elements never leave it, or at least not within the system lag which is now 45min. This is supposed to be a streaming job - how can I make it flush and write the data? This is beam version 2.13.0. Thank you.

UPDATE - StackDriver log (no errors) for the step to write data to BigQuery:

[image: Write step StackDriver log]

I can also add that this works if I use the DirectRunner in the cloud (but only for small amounts of data) and either runner if I insert row by row using the java interface to BigQuery (but that is at least two orders of magnitude too slow to start with).

Comment: Try run it with DirectRunner from your local machine. It will log out a more verbose error messages. Sometimes in cases likes this it helped for me.

Comment: Unfortunately not, as that works fine with no errors - it writes to the table. There is one other difference. When deployed, there is a PubSub read node added at the start of the pipeline, which I cannot easily test exactly on a local run (it results in large amounts of data), otherwise it is the same. When I deploy it in the cloud it doesn't work - and also without any error messages.

Comment: Did you create the dataset where you would like to write? Or do you have correct permissions to write there?

Comment: Yes, via Deployment Manager. I can write from the pipeline running on my local computer. We have other dataflow jobs deployed through Cloud Build, which can write. I don't think it gets as far as actually trying to write, I think it is still trying to order/organise data to do so efficiently (but obviously failing so far).

Comment: My last idea to debugging the issue is try change the subscription on the pipeline and feed it only with a few sample messages. If the pipeline can write them out, maybe the window in the groupByKey step can't stand the load. Check the VM's stats (memory, disk, CPU), maybe it's overloaded.

Comment: Ah, thank you, but I am already doing that - a single PubSub message may result in millions of rows streamed from elsewhere. I could try removing some steps and feeding a URL to a small test file, however. But what is the window in the BigQueryIO GroupByKey step doing.. can I do anything to change it? I just want it to store my data ("my part of the pipeline" does not do any grouping or windowing).

Comment: @nsandersen Did you solve it? I've seen similar issues when running a backfill and hence try to stream tablerows into a table that is partitioned by ingestion time and the tablerows belong to a partition that is older than 31 days.

Answer (score 1):

You might try changing your retry policy to `InsertRetryPolicy.retryTransientErrors()`. The `alwaysRetry()` policy will cause the pipeline to appear to stop making progress if there is some configuration error, for example the BigQuery table not existing or not having permission to access it. The failures are always retried so they are never reported as failures.

You can also check the worker logs in Stackdriver Logging. Do this by clicking on the "Stackdriver" link in the upper corner of the step log pane. Full directions are in the [Dataflow logging documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/logging#cloud_dataflow_worker_log_example).

Comment: With or without that policy, I see no errors in StackDriver. (In fact it says: "No errors have been received in this time period.".) Interestingly I see the first PubSub step redelivering the message triggering the pipeline several times. I wonder if this is because it hasn't been ack'ed, because the write step doesn't write anything and therefore doesn't pass information about what has been persisted back up the pipeline.

Comment: It sounds like you are on the "STACK TRACES" tab and not "StackDriver".
If you have no logs then either the worker has not started or something has gone wrong with outputting logs. You should contact GCP support. The stackdriver worker logs are extreamly verbose and you should see warnings and errors when the system boots. The stackdriver page displays "No entries found matching current filter." when there are no logs and the URL starts with https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer

Comment: Thank you - don't seem to see any errors there either (? - picture attached).

Comment: You have the right log viewer now, you should be seeing log messages. Looks like your filter is only showing logs 7 hours after the job started? Try removing the time filter ("timestamp >=" line from the query) then hit submit filter. Also try the "Load newer logs" button.

Comment: The screenshot might look old, but it is representative - the write steps do not log anything.